# Error in the coding : TypeError : list indices must be integer, not str

Tags: python, csv

Code is importing another file, which is working perfectly.

But, there is a problem in the line where I try to import the csv file, with a column called 'account key', returning the TypeError above.

```
import file_import as fi
```

Function for collectively finding data necessary from a csv file.

```
def unique_students(csv_file):
    unique_students_list = set()
    for information in csv_file:
        unique_students_list.add(csv_file["account_key"])
    return len(unique_students_list)

#enrollment_num_rows = len(fi.enrollments)  
#engagement_num_rows = len(fi.daily_engagement)           
#submission_num_rows = len(fi.project_submissions)    

#enrollment_num_unique_students = unique_students(fi.enrollments)
#engagement_num_unique_students = unique_students(fi.daily_engagement)
#submission_num_unique_students = unique_students(fi.project_submissions)
```

Comment: is csv_file documented to be a dictionary, or a list?

Comment: It is supposed to be a list.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

`csv_file["account_key"]`

Lists expect a numeric index. As far as I know, only dictionaries accept String indices.

I'm not entirely sure what this is supposed to do; I think your logic is flawed. You bind `information` in the `for` loop, then never use it. Even if the list did accept a string index, all it would do is populate the Set with the same information over and over since the `for` loop body remains the same same every loop. This would only work if you were expecting `csv_file` to be a custom container type that had side effects when indexed (like advancing some internal counter).